# Speech synthesized phone call, Android?

Tags: android, speech-synthesis

In Android, can I have an app that makes a speech-synthesized phone call? That is, I have a string of text that I want spoken when the phone call is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible. You cannot play audio into a phone call.

Comment: ...unless the device is in speakerphone mode.